# Python: Is it possible to construct an instance of a class, if i know the name as a string?

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to initialize an instance with values from a database. I know the class name, because its the same as the table name.

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
          ...

values = (arg1, arg2, arg3)
className = "MyClass"

instance = ?
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Classes are first-class values; if you can avoid the string and just take a reference to the class, do that. `className = MyClass; instance = className(*values)`. If you *must* get a string for some reason, set up your own dict mapping expected strings to class references, like `d = {'MyClass': MyClass}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a metaclass to register every instance of a database model, with a dictionary to get a class, given a name:

```
class Models(type):
    classes = {}

    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, attrs):
        newclass = super(Models, cls).__new__(cls, clsname, bases, attrs)
        Models.register(newclass)  # here is your register function
        return newclass

    @classmethod
    def register(cls, new_class):
        Models.classes[new_class.__name__] = new_class


class MyClass(metaclass=Models):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
          ...


values = ("a", "b", "c")
className = "MyClass"

instance = Models.classes.get(className)(*values)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thats a lot of new stuff for me, but it works and I'm trying now to understand. :)

Comment: @AbuBakr Metaclasses are pretty advanced and can be confusing to understand, but are useful for stuff like this